# React Js look at items in array and check for null

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I have an array that i am getting from my Web API and I want to be able to check for any null fields and if they are change them from null to `''` how would i go about this

to read the actual array i need to do this

```
console.log(result.data[0])
```

which will return the BuildingNumber as null. how would i check every item if it is null or not as if your on a different person they might have multiple null fields.

Comment: This is unclear. Show the mentioned array and specify your desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use a map function `arr.map(e => e === null ? '' : e)`

Comment: To improve it you have to check if the value is `null` otherwise it will returns an empty string also for 0, undefined and false.

Comment: @emattiazzi your right I always forget about 0, edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you're environment supports ES6 specification then you can use the [array's map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which will iterate over every item in your array and return a new array. During this process you can transform the given element as you'd like. For example:

```
var apiResponse = [1, 2, null, 3];
var fixedArray = apiResponse.map(function(item) {
    if (item === null) {
        item = '';
    }
    return item;
});
```

`fixedArray` will then have the following array `[1, 2, '', 3]`.

If you're not using ES6, you can use a common loop to check for each item and push to the new array accordingly.

```
var apiResponse = [1, 2, null, 3];
var fixedArray = [];

apiResponse.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item === null) {
       fixedArray.push('');
    } else {
       fixedArray.push(item);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your implementation of .map callback is wrong. You have to return the item.

Comment: @emattiazzi Indeed! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that what you want to achieve is: change every item that has the value of `null` inside an Array to an empty string.

This is a good chance to use `.map`.

```
var resultWithChangedElements = result.data.map(function(item) {
  return item === null ? '' : item;
})
```

You can read more on how it works on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map